# Python: Adding date from file twice at end of data from separate file in array

Tags: python, arrays

so I need some assistance with a kind of specific problem. I have .composite (ex: RR0063_0011.composite) files in which the second columns (intensities) are read into an array, but I need to add the date (Modified Julian Date) from the second column of a separate file twice at the end of each row before the array is transposed and saved. Example input files:

Data **(.composite)** file:

Bin#.....Intensity

```
1. -0.234987
2. 0.87734
...
512. -0.65523
```

Modified Julian Date file:

File from which MJD is grabbed.....MJD

```
RR0063_0011.profs   55105.07946
RR0023_0061.profs   53495.367377
RR0022_0041.profs   53492.307631
```

This is the code for reading the data into the array and making the mjd.txt file. All this works so far, I just need to add the MJD *twice* to the end of the corresponding .composite row. Now, I have very little knowledge of Python, but this is the code I have currently.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import glob
import numpy as np
import os

psrname = sys.argv[1]
file_list = glob.glob('*.composite')

cols = [1] 
data = []
for f in file_list:
    # Split the filename from the extension to use later    
    filename = os.path.splitext('{0}'.format(f))
    data.append(np.loadtxt(f, usecols=cols))
    print data

# Run 'vap' (a PSRCHIVE command) to grap the MJD from the .profs file for each observation and write out to a file called 'mjd.txt'
os.system('vap -nc mjd ../{0}/{0}.profs >> mjd.txt' .format(filename[0]))

# Put the MJDs only (from 'mjd.txt') in an array called mjd_array
mjd_array = np.genfromtxt('mjd.txt', dtype=[('filename_2','S40'),('mjd','f8')])

# Check if working
print mjd_array['mjd'][7]

arr = np.vstack(data)

transposed_arr = np.transpose(arr)
print transposed_arr

fout = np.savetxt(psrname + '.total', transposed_arr, delimiter='   ')
```

The MJDs aren't in order with the .composite files, and at the end I need to sort all the columns by MJD before saving.

Thank you for any help!

Desired output:

Intensity

.....

Intensity

MJD

MJD

```
-0.234987
2. 0.87734
...
-0.65523
55105.07946
55105.07946
```

Comment: Could you provide examples of both input files and desired output file, please?

Comment: @albert Edited for clarity! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not need the additional `2.` in your sample output (which might be a copy-and-paste-error from sample input), you can first read the dates from the dates file and use this as a kind of look-up table:

```
import os
import numpy as np


# function to read dates from generated mjd file
# and create look-up table (is a list of lists)
def read_mjd_file():
    with open('mjd.txt') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    lines = [line.split() for line in lines]        
    return lines


# function for date look-up
# filename is first list element, date is second
def get_date(base_name):
    for l in lines:
        if l[0].startswith(base_name):
            return l[1]


# function to read data from data file
def extract_data(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        data = np.loadtxt(f, usecols=[1])
    return data


# generate mjd file at first
# os.system(...)


# generate look-up table from mjd file
lines = read_mjd_file()


# walk through all files given in directory and filter for desired file type
for file_name in os.listdir():
    if file_name.endswith('.composite'):
        base_name = file_name.split('.')[0]
        date = get_date(base_name)
        data = extract_data(file_name)
        out = np.append(data, 2*[date])


print(out)
```

You might adapt this approach to your specific needs since this is just a proof of concept in order to give you a hint. Personally, I prefer `os.listdir()` to `glob.glob()`. In addition, I don't think you need to use `numpy` for this rather easy task. Python's standard `csv` module should also do the job. However, `numpy`'s functions are far more comfortable. So, if you need `numpy` for further tasks you might keep it. If not, rewriting the snippet using `csv` module should not be a big deal.

`mjd.txt` looks like:

```
RR0063_0011.profs   55105.07946
RR0023_0061.profs   53495.367377
RR0022_0041.profs   53492.307631
```

`RR0023_0061.composite` looks like:

```
1. -0.234987
2. 0.87734
512. -0.65523
```

output (variable `out`) is a `np.array`:

```
['-0.234987' '0.87734' '-0.65523' '53495.367377' '53495.367377']
```

Comment: Thanks so much! But I'm a bit confused - the file that contains the data I need is a .composite file. The composite files don't contain the MJD, which is why I was grabbing it from the .profs files, which are in other directories.

Comment: @astrokid: seems that I still do not get your file structure and the specific file contents. How many files do you have to have a look at in order to grab all the information you need? Do the .profs files and the . composite files have same filenames (with different extensions) and form a pair? If so, you need to look up the time stamp using the file base name instead of its complete filename. Could you please clarify? I'll implement changes to my snippet after clarification if needed.

Comment: So in the directory I am in, I have only composite files, which is the first file I gave the example of. The MJD file is created in the line containing os.system where the profs files are accessed in other directories specific to the filename of the file currently in queue. Ex: RR0001_0001.composite is opened, the second column is read, vap grabs the MJD from the RR0001_0001.profs file in the directory RR0001_0001, then RR0002_0002 and so on.